# How can I utilize 3 HTML input boxes to calculate the area of a triangle?

Tags: javascript, input

I'm new to JavaScript and to this community.

I'm trying to complete questions I found on W3Academy to calculate the area of a triangle using the three side lengths.  I challenged myself to include HTML inputs rather than declaring the numbers as variables within JavaScript.  I am running this in JS Bin with inputs 5, 4 and 3, however it isn't yielding any results.  What is wrong with the code?

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="number" id="side1"/>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="number" id="side2"/>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="number" id="side3"/>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button onclick="area()">Calculate</button>
  <br>
  <p id = "output">Result</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my JS:

```
var sideA = document.getElementById("side1").value;
var sideB = document.getElementById("side2").value;
var sideC = document.getElementById("side3").value;
var p = sideA + sideB + sideC;
var result;

function area() {
  result = sqrt(p * (p - sideA) * (p - sideB) *(p - sideC));
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Comment: What is the question ? You should specify your problem.

Comment: **Two thoughts.** Make sure you `parseInt` or `parseFloat` the side variables into numbers before you try to use them mathematically. Also are you giving the DOM time to load before executing your JS -- use `window.onload`?

Comment: Sorry - the question was what am I doing wrong?  I am trying to run in JS Bin using inputs 5, 4 and 3, however clicking the button yields no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** you're retrieving the values of the input fields at the beginning of your code, that means all of your input fields values are null, to fix this you should move those lines inside the `area()` function, like this:

```
function area() {
  var sideA = document.getElementById("side1").value,
    sideB = document.getElementById("side2").value,
    sideC = document.getElementById("side3").value,
    p = sideA + sideB + sideC,
    result = Math.sqrt(p * (p - sideA) * (p - sideB) * (p - sideC));
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result;
}
```

**Second:** you should use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) for the values of the input fields. or ,instead, you can simply add **`+`** sign, like this:

```
var sideA = +document.getElementById("side1").value;
```

**Third:** I believe it is `Math.sqrt()` not `sqrt()`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to include where the js file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="The file path javascript"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
```

Personally I would do like this:

```
var sideA = $("side1").val();
var sideB = $("side2").val();
var sideC = $("side3").val();

area(sideA, sideB, sideC);


function area(a, b, c) {
  var p = a + b + c;
  var result = sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) *(p - c));
  $("output").html(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Is this in JQuery?  I was hoping to see what was wrong with my JS.  I didn't think I needed to include where the js file was for this example, since I am using JS Bin.

Comment: Yes it´s JQuery, it´s necesary to include it